# hashtags for posted yammer messages using yammer REST API

Tags: yammer

For any existing yammer messages, is there a way to create a tag (i.e., hashtag) programmatically using the yammer rest API. The URI: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/:Topic_ID.json accepts only GET requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to include #YOURHASHTAG in a new reply.

Comment: I just want to tag a bunch of messages that contain a keyword WITHOUT sending any message.

Comment: I don't believe that's currently possible. The only thing I can think of is, you could delete your reply afterwards and the hashtag will persist.